# Find out if the value on blur is different as compared with "the focus one" (JavaScript + jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find out if the user changed text field or select option and if so, then do some stuff. I'm using jQuery too.

```
$('.c').on('focus',function(){
    var origval=this.value;
    $(this).on('blur',function(){
        var newval=this.value;
        if(origval==newval){
            alert('not changed');
        }
        else{
            alert('changed');
        }
    });
});
```

But this is not right solution, I'm doing something wrong. Sometimes it alerts "changed" although it shouldn't. Could anyone suggest me where is the fault? Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/QGag2/1/

Comment: Probably my functions are poorly laid out. Aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

blur event is getting subscribed to multiple times since this happens on every focus.

unsubscribe to blur event before subscribing (off method), or unsubscribe to the event after blur has happened.

```
$(this).off('blur').on('blur',function(){
```

Comment: +1 i always forget you can call these inline like that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to nest the event handlers. They can be independent as follows so that when one, focus, occurs the value just gets saved and the comparison is done when the other, blue happens.

```
$(function() {
    var formElement = $( '.c' );
    formElement.on( 'focus', function() {
        $( this ).data( 'focus', this.value );
    });

    formElement.on( 'blur', function() {
        $( this ).data( 'blur', this.value );
        if( $( this ).data( 'focus' ) === $( this ).data( 'blur' ) ) {
            alert( this.nodeName +' not changed' );
        } else {
            alert( this.nodeName +' changed' );
        }
    });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/QGag2/2/)